# Shortest path with two objectives

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, dijkstra, np-hard

I am interested in writing an algorithm to find the shortest path with two objective (ex. time and safety). 
For example, in the graph below, black number is the travel time and red number is the probability of a user experiencing an incident. The goal is to find the best path with the best overall cost.

Total cost = time + (probability of an incident in this route)*(time cost of an incident)

What type of problem is this? Is this a NP-hard problem?
[image: example]

Comment: What do you mean by best path with best cost? You should define best in quantitative terms of cost and probabilty of incident.

Comment: You need to define how you go from the pairs of costs on the edges to a single (and therefore comparable) cost on the whole path.

Comment: Just computing the "probability of an incident in this route" is quite difficult since you need to know all the combinations of probabilities that multiple roads have incidents. However, if they're mutually exclusive (as in: at most one road can have an incident), then I think you can get away with replacing all the edge weights with their _expected_ costs (ie. per road: time + prob * cost of incident)

Comment: I agree with previous comments, and also want clarification of "time-cost of an incident". In practice when traveling the "time-cost of an incident" can exceed the total time for the path (train/plane getting stuck for hours - flat tire on bad roads needing repair); and in other cases you can see that the edge has an incident before taking it.

Comment: @AlexReinking I believe that edge-cost (time+prob*cost of incident) is instead possible when probabilities are independent, not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @HansOlsson - no, I meant mutually exclusive. The probability of an incident happening on a path is the probability that an incident occurs on _at least one edge_ in the path. For simplicity, assume we have a path of length 2. Let X_e be the event that an incident occurs. Then P(X_e1 or X_e2) = P(X_e1) + P(X_e2) - P(X_e1 and X_e2). The latter term is 0 when they're mutually exclusive. It is their _product_ when they are independent.

Comment: @AlexReinking There are two possible variants: the cost of an incident is constant regardless of the path and incidents are mutually exclusive, the cost of an incident on an edge may only depend on that edge (it may be the same for all edges) and probabilities are independent (so we can compute an edge-weight taking into account the incident-cost for that edge). The second alternative implies that for multiple incidents we just add up their costs.

Answer (score 2):

**First**, if your edge weights can be combined via compatible units through convolution, scaling, or something else that results in forming a new ordered *semiring*, then Dijkstra's algorithm will work as expected over that semiring.

**Second**, if your edge weights are fundamentally different, you can settle for a *Pareto-optimal* path. That is, a path for which you cannot improve one criteria without worsening the other. Often, this is the best you can do. Two papers that might be of interest are:

[A bicriterion shortest path algorithm](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0377221782902053) by Climacao and Martins

[A bicriterion Pareto-optimal path algorithm](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268618245_A_bicriterion_Pareto-optimal_path_algorithm) by Tung and Chew

**In your case**, if you make some strong assumptions about the events of your "incidents" -- namely that they are mutually exclusive -- then you can replace your edge weights with `time + expected time due to an incident`.

This is because if `X_e` is the event that an incident occurs on edge `e`, then `P(X_e1 or X_e2) = P(X_e1) + P(X_e2) - P(X_e1 and X_e2) = P(X_e1) + P(X_e2)` by their mutual exclusivity. Then the expected cost of any path `e1 ... eN` is `cost(e1) + ... + cost(eN) + incident cost * P(X_e1 or ... or. X_eN) = cost(e1) + ... + cost(eN) + incident cost * (P(X_e1) + ... + P(X_eN)) = (cost(e1) + incident cost * P(X_e1)) + ... + (cost(eN) + incident cost * P(X_eN)) = E(cost of e1) + ... + E(cost of eN)` which is just the sum of the expected costs of each edge, independently of one another.